# How make a superuser after signup a user?

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model and I just want to All Publisher users become superuser too, but I don't know How to do it??

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_publisher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and This is my View

```
def signup(response):
    form = SignUpForm()
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(response, "registration/signup.html", {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve instance from `Form`, set is_superuser and save instance:

```py
def signup(response):
    form = SignUpForm()
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            if instance.is_publisher:
                instance.is_superuser = True
            instance.save()

        return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(response, "registration/signup.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: This is make all signup users superuser instead of those who is_publisher is TRUE, with an IF before is_superuser problem solved.

Comment: @Amir correct, I did not see this condition